# If page is unpublished go to the next available page

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I'm creating a webcomic using Django. I have a status choice field in my model: 1 to publish a page and 0 to unpublish it.

```
STATUS = (
(0,"Draft"),
(1,"Publish"))
```

I have created two functions: the first one to go to the previous page and the second one to go to the next page.

```
def get_previous(self):
    previous = Page.objects.filter(status=1).get(number=self.number - 1)
    if previous.number > 0:
        return reverse('comic_page', args=[previous.chapter.slug, previous.number])
    return None

def get_next(self):
    last = Page.objects.filter(status=1).last()
    next = Page.objects.filter(status=1).get(number=self.number + 1)
    if next.number <= last.number:
        return reverse('comic_page', args=[next.chapter.slug, next.number])
    return None
```

It works as expected when all the pages are published, but when one of the pages is unpublished it doesn't go to the next available page but just refreshes the page.

I tried creating another queryset with only unpublished pages and then checking if the page exists in that queryset and jumping 2 page numbers instead of 1 but it did not work.

```
def get_previous(self):
    previous = Page.objects.filter(status=1).get(number=self.number - 1)
    unpublished = Page.objects.filter(status=0)
    if previous in unpublished:
        previous = Page.objects.filter(status=1).get(number=self.number - 2)
        return reverse('comic_page', args=[previous.chapter.slug, previous.number])

    if previous.number > 0:
        return reverse('comic_page', args=[previous.chapter.slug, previous.number])
    return None
```

Any suggestions are appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `get` and making an *exact* lookup on the `number` make a *less than* or *greater than* lookup ([`lt` / `gt` lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#gt)) on the number with an ordering and use the [`first` / `last` methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#first):

```
def get_previous(self):
    previous = Page.objects.filter(status=1, number__lt=self.number).order_by('number').last()
    if previous is not None:
        return reverse('comic_page', args=[previous.chapter.slug, previous.number])
    return None

def get_next(self):
    next = Page.objects.filter(status=1, number__gt=self.number).order_by('number').first()
    if next is not None:
        return reverse('comic_page', args=[next.chapter.slug, next.number])
    return None
```